# Cancel current speech utterance if user changes to a different SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, svg, speech-synthesis

I have a web based application with an svg. When the user moves their finger over the screen, different descriptions are given depending on what part of the svg they are on. However, I want to cancel the current speech utterance if the user moves onto a different svg path. Currently, the speech synthesis api will continue to read out the description, even if the user is on a different path.
The reason for `if ('speechSynthesis' in window)` is so the rest of my script will run on Firefox.

Here is my speech synthesis function:

```
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
   var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
   var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
   msg.voice = 'native';
   msg.rate = 2;
}
```

....

```
function vibStart(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      e = document.elementFromPoint(event.touches.item(0).clientX, event.touches.item(0).clientY);
      for (var i = 0; i<paths.length +1; i += 1) {
               if (e.id == "path" + i) {
                           if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
                             msg.text = document.getElementById("desc" + i).firstChild.data;
                             speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
                             msg.addEventListener('end', function () {
                                 speechSynthesis.cancel();
                             });
                           }
               }
       }
 }
```

Is there some way of storing the speech text as a variable, and then checking this against the e.id and if they are the same, to cancel the speech utterance?

**EDIT**

I've tried adding `speechSynthesis.cancel();` before `msg.text`, but this doesn't solve the issue either. While it does cancel the utterance when the user moves onto a new path, it doesn't start the new utterance straight away.

Comment: Why not just store the e.id each time and only start the speech thingy when that changes? You could save it a variable in the same scope as the `msg` for example.

Comment: @Kerstomaat do you have an example code?

Comment: Nope, not really, have no idea what (the rest) of your code looks like and have never worked with the Speech API. Maybe you could make a minimal working demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1):

Developing on @Kerstomaat's suggestion, I solved my problem by simply creating a global variable called `spoken` and setting it to `null`.

I then changed the code block beginning `if ('speechSynthesis' in window)` to:

```
('speechSynthesis' in window) {
   var speech = document.getElementById("desc" + i);
   if (spoken !== speech) { 
      speechSynthesis.cancel()      
      msg.text = document.getElementById("desc" + i).firstChild.data;
      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
      spoken = speech;
}
```

This resulted in the descriptions firing whenever you are a new path, and for the previous description to stop playing. Seemed to fix the problem!